# Views - Clicked element + corresponding content

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type which contains the following fields

- title
- text body
- image

An I need to achieve something like below

[image]

The 4-image grid is a view which covers 50% of the page. The green coloured box represents the clicked image. I need the text-area right next to the view to contain the the text corresponding to the image which is clicked.

Is it possible to achieve this using views alone?

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely possible! Apart from views it goes without saying that ajax is essential, except if you want a page reload when an image is clicked.

Comment: @mchar : thanks , I don't want a page reload. I've enabled ajax for this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create the View, the block and the required fields (order matters).

Block's instructions (page can be different):

- Format:

  - Grid
  - Number of columns: `2`
- Fields:

  - Nid: Exclude from display
  - Title:

    - Link this field to the original piece of content: `Unchecked`
    - REWRITE RESULTS `->` Rewrite the output of field `->` Output this field as a link `->` Link path: `ajax-link/nojs/[nid]`
    - Link class: `use-ajax`
  - Image:

    - Link image to: `Nothing`
    - REWRITE RESULTS `->` ... Same as "Title"
    - Link class: `use-ajax`

So, the title's or image's `url` should have this structure: `hook-menu-registered-path/nojs/argument`

**Step 2:** Create a custom module and implement the following code.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu.
 */
function custom_module_menu() {
  // A menu callback is required when using ajax outside of the Form API.
  $items['ajax-link'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_custom_module_response',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 *  Callback function.
 * 
 * @param int $nid
 *   Either a valid node id or 0 (zero) if not available.
 *
 *  @param string $type
 *   Either 'ajax' or 'nojs. Type is simply the normal URL argument to this URL.
 *
 *  @return string|array
 *    If $type == 'ajax', returns an array of AJAX Commands,
 *   otherwise, just returns the content, which will end up being a page.
 */
function _custom_module_response($type, $nid = 0) {
  $output = _custom_module_node_load($nid);
  if ($type == 'ajax') {
    $commands = array();
    // Selector: A jQuery selector string, either a .class or #id.
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('.selector', '<div class="selector">' . $output . '</div>');
    $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
    ajax_deliver($page);
  }
  else {
    $output = isset($output) ? '<div class="no-content">' . $output . '</div>' : t('Node does not exist!');
    return $output;
  }
}

/**
 *  Node loader function.
 *  
 *  @return string
 *   The themed node in its define view mode.
 */
function _custom_module_node_load($nid = 0) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  if ($node) {
    $pre_rendered_node = node_view($node, $view_mode = 'full');
    return theme('node', $pre_rendered_node);
  }
}
```

**Step 3:** Load the necessary library. I chose the `template.php` file to do it.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_views_view.
 */
function custom_theme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  if ($view->name == 'my_view_name') {
    // drupal_add_library is invoked automatically when a form element has the
    // '#ajax' property, but since we are not rendering a form here, we have to
    // do it ourselves.
    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
    $output = '<div class="selector">' . $vars['rows'];
    $output .= '</div>';
    $vars['rows'] = $output;
  }
}
```

Now, should only the body field must be displayed (or a certain set of fields) I suggest the definition of a [view mode](https://www.drupal.org/node/1577752) per case, then define that view mode to the [`node_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_view/7.x) function.

---

**Note:**

[Ajax framework's](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7.x) "magic" class: `use-ajax`

> By adding the 'use-ajax' class to a link, the link will be loaded via an Ajax call. When using this method, the href of the link can contain '/nojs/' as part of the path. When the Ajax framework makes the request, it will convert this to '/ajax/'. The server is then able to easily tell if this request was made through an actual Ajax request or in a degraded state, and respond appropriately.

**Ref.:** [Drupal examples modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples), [How to use Drupal 7's built-in Ajax Framework](http://www.seanbuscay.com/ajax-reader-demo/)

Comment: Thankyou so much. I've already had found a workaround since I ran out of time. I used two view grids and wrote some jquery to add an class which then is used to selectively display content at the right pane. However, this looks exactly like what I was looking for. I'll keep you posted when I implement this. Again, hats off !!